# Error: NullPointerException when starting activity on devices without NFC

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, operators, nfc

I have created an application for NFC phones. The app should start one activity if the device supports NFC and another if it does not.

So on start up I have done with this to filter NFC vs. non-NFC phones:

```
mNfc = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
if (mNfc == null | !mNfc.isEnabled()) {
    Intent a = new Intent(AA.this, AB.class);
    a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(a);
} else {
    Intent b = new Intent(AA.this, BB.class);
    b.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(b);
}
```

This works fine with NFC phones (even when NFC is disabled). However, on non-NFC phones this leads to the following exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

For testing purposes, I have done this on non-NFC phones

```
if (mNfc == null) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "This device doesn't support NFC.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
}
```

This works without any exception and I see the toast message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a bitwise OR operator (`|`) in the expression

```
if (mNfc == null | !mNfc.isEnabled()) {
```

This causes both `mNfc == null` and `!mNfc.isEnabled()` to be evaluated. As a result, you call `isEnabled()` on a `null` object reference (`mNfc`).

When you change the expression to use a logical OR operator (`||`)

```
if (mNfc == null || !mNfc.isEnabled()) {
```

then the expression `mNfc == null` will be evaluated first, and as it evaluates to `true` (which implies that the whole logical expression must evaluate to `true`), the remaining part of the expression will not be evaluated at all. Hence, `mNfc.isEnabled()` is not invoked in that case.